# MySQL Workbench cannot connect from home to Google Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I cannot connect to my Google Cloud SQL database from my Macbook Pro using MySQL Workbench.

I have read the help file here:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/admin-tools

I have added an authorized IP address for my IP per
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-ip#add

I created a user for the database with it set to allow to connect from any host. I get the error "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XX.XXX.XX.XXX' (60)

I have also attempted to telnet and get a consistent error that I am unable to connect to the remote host

As far as I know, I've followed all the steps but it really seems I'm getting blocked even before the server. I am trying to connect from home and I don't believe my home firewall is blocking things. I am wondering if there's something I need to open up on the GCE firewall but I have successfully connected to this database from other outside tools (e.g., Zapier).

Comment: You might want to try the devops sister site on stack exchange

Answer (score 0):

Your best action right now would be to create a proxy with public IP address.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app

This link will walk you through that process. If this doesn’t solve your issue, then taking your question to ServerFault (Stackoverflow sister site) might give you a better idea of how to fix your issue.